# How to take screenshot in Boot Camp?

Tags: keyboard, bootcamp, windows

I have MacBook Pro Retina running Windows 8.1. I do not have a PrtScr key. Also, shift+fn+f11 key combination doesn't work. What is the shortcut to take screenshots?

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>⇧ shift</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> is the correct keyboard shortcut to emulate a Print Screen in Windows, however this shortcut requires the Boot Camp drivers to be installed and be running in Windows. Make sure you have the drivers installed correctly and check whether the keyboard is configured to require fn in Boot Camp Control Panel.

Answer (score 4):

Use the **Snipping Tool** that ships with Windows, it's made for that exact purpose. The Windows help page is [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/use-snipping-tool-capture-screen-shots#1TC=windows-8), info found using [this search tool](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=windows%208.1%20screenshot&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=2hgPVc6_EMP6atLmgJgH) ;-)

Comment: It would be useful to detail the process instead of punting to some help page.

Answer (score 2):

now win10 support shift+win+s hotkey to take a  screenshot, I give up this task by  using touch bar of windows in macbook.

Answer (score 1):

If you hear the click sound when taking a screen shot the the shot has been taken and it is in your Clipboard.

To get it, open any application (like paint or other) and use the "Paste command" to see it/modify and save as a file in a location of your choosing.

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> (and also <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) will only work if you have the following setting in **Boot Camp Control Panel** turned off (untick the checkbox):

**Keyboard** tab > **Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys**

Extra tip:

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> = Captures the full screen

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> = Captures the current active window

Answer (score 0):

I just messed around using Bootcamp Windows 10 on Mac laptop, the issue is not the control, it is the setup:

First, set up OneDrive

Press <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>

Prompt will ask you if you want to save screenshots to OneDrive: Yes

For future screenshots use the original command of <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>